# How to assign value to variable in list [PYTHON]

Tags: python

How can I do something like this on python :

```py
class Game:
    
    def __init__(self, size: int):
        self.settings = { 
            'timeout_turn' = 0
            'timeout_match' = 0
            'max_memory' = 0
            'time_left' = 2147483647
            'game_type' = 0
            'rule' = 0
            'evaluate' = 0
            'folder' = './'
            }
```

there is an error, I think this is not the right way to do it but I didn't find an other solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This code does not fit with the title. There is no list here. Are you trying to create a dictionary?

Comment: yea maybe, well I don't know how to describe this, so I identify it as a 'list'

Comment: Well, understanding what is a list and what is a dictionary is the most basic thing if you want to program anything. I would highly recommend that you spend a couple of hours on going through a tutorial and learning the basics. Otherwise you will only be guessing and never understanding what is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make it work you need to replace the  `=` by and `:` and add a `,` after every entry.

```
class Game:
    def __init__(self, size: int):
        self.settings = { 
            'timeout_turn': 0,
            'timeout_match': 0,
            'max_memory': 0,
            'time_left': 2147483647,
            'game_type': 0,
            'rule': 0,
            'evaluate': 0,
            'folder': './'
        }
```

By doing this you are creating a class variable named `settings` that is of type dictionary. Dictionaries are also known as maps in other languages. They use immutable values as indexes (keys) instead of numbers like in lists.

Answer (score 2):

here you go but it's a dictionnary not a list

```
class Game:
    def __init__(self, size: int):
    self.settings = { 
        'timeout_turn' : 0,
        'timeout_match' : 0,
        'max_memory' : 0,
        'time_left' : 2147483647,
        'game_type' : 0,
        'rule' : 0,
        'evaluate' : 0,
        'folder' : './',
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi  I Hope you are doing well!

Because you are using `dict` the syntax should have `:` instead of `=`:

```py
class Game:

    def __init__(self, size: int) -> None:
        """Initialize."""

        self.settings = {
            "timeout_turn": 0,
            "timeout_match": 0,
            "max_memory": 0,
            "time_left": 2147483647,
            "game_type": 0,
            "rule": 0,
            "evaluate": 0,
            "folder": "./",
        }
```

or if you want to have it as attributes you can do this:

```py
class Game:

    def __init__(self, size: int) -> None:
        """Initialize."""

        self.timeout_turn = 0
        self.timeout_match = 0

        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want your settings data to be a dictionnary `:` instead of `=` to affect value to the key (variable name).

If you just want to create new variables you could do it like that :

```
class Game:

def __init__(self, size: int):
    self.timeout_turn=0
    self.max_memory=0
    ....
```

Comment: There is a stray `}`